# Dialogflow bug webhook node js facebook chatbot

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

create a chatbot with dialogflow and a webhook with node js. Sometimes requests do not reach the webhook and others it takes more than five seconds to respond. It's something that happens randomly and that forces me to use intent's responses. what is this about? How can I improve it?

I have deployed it in heroku, on my pc with ngrok and on a server that has ngnix, the bug still happens. What I do is send a value to the webhook to validate it or send it to an api rest. It's very random of 20 tests that I do happen about five times. Has something similar ever happened to you?

Sometimes I only send the value to validate that is greater than or equal to x and that it is number, most of the times it works, returns the next question of the dialog in others the chatbot does not respond to the user. It seems that the webhook rejects the request.

Comment: What does the JSON log output in DialogFlow say?

Comment: Yes, it is observed that the webhook does not respond because it takes more than 5 seconds since it is consulted to an api rest, although there are cases where it does not respond and api rest is not consulted. Where can I see more details of the log? apart from the "Raw interaction log" window